# Separate a Name into Different Columns using Tidyr

Tags: r, tidyr

This question is an extension of another post titled - Separate “Name” into “FirstName” and “LastName” columns of data frame - and the data frame is provided below.

```
NAME <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope-Douglas', 'Muhammad Arnab Halwai')
TITLE <- c("assistant", "manager", "assistant", "specialist")
tteam<- data.frame(NAME, TITLE)
```

A nice code was provided to show how to use `tidyr` to separate each name into first and last name. I have a situation where there are names with three parts, such as the name provided in the example - "Muhammad Arnab Halwai". I believe the code below will separate the name into "Muhammad" and "Arnab Halwai". I'm trying to reconfigure the code to create "Muhammad Arnab" and "Halwai".

```
library(tidyr)
extract(tteam, NAME, c("FirstName", "LastName"), "([^ ]+) (.*)")
```

Comment: You can get the desired result with just `extract(tteam, NAME, c("FirstName", "LastName"), '(.+) (.+)')` or `separate(tteam, NAME, c("FirstName", "LastName"), ' (?=[^ ]+$)')`. Check your data, though; suffixes or articles ("Charles de Gaulle") will wreck this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got to switch up the regex a bit:

```
extract(tteam, NAME, c("FirstName", "LastName"), "(.*) ([^ ]+)$")

#       FirstName     LastName      TITLE
# 1           John          Doe  assistant
# 2          Peter         Gynn    manager
# 3          Jolie Hope-Douglas  assistant
# 4 Muhammad Arnab       Halwai specialist
```